# How to make expander not to extend toolbar width?

Tags: wpf, size, width, toolbar, expander

I have a expander in a tool bar. When I expand the expander to toolbar increases its width so it can contain the expanded expander. I would like the tool bar to stay the same and expander to expand bellow tool bar, so the toolbar doesn't become so wide? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the toolbar is going to expand to accomodate the expander or if you set the width to a specific value, it will cut the expander off.  Typically what I do in cases like this is host the Expander outside of the toolbar and make it look like it is a part of it.